# Remove an array column from a CSV file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, csv

I have a CSV file, `in.csv`, which has an integer array column:

```
1,2,4,"{100,200,300}",,1
1,2,4,"{100,200,300,400,500}",,2
1,2,4,"{100,200,300,600.900,1200,1500}",1,3
```

I want to have an output file, `out.csv`, like:

```
1,2,4,,1
1,2,4,,2
1,2,4,1,3
```

I tried:

```
cut -d , -f4 -- complement in.csv > out.csv
```

But it did not work out.  (I also have the fifth column which has value for third row but not for others).

Answer (score 1):

Using [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

```
$ csvcut -C 4 in.csv
1,2,4,,1
1,2,4,,2
1,2,4,1,3
```

The `-C` flag specifies what columns to remove.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work

```
awk -F'[,]' '{print $1","$2","$3","$(NF-1)","$NF}' in.csv
```

- `-F'[,]'`    this for sit the delimiter to ','
- `$NF`        give you the last item

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` you can simply do:

```
sed 's/,"{.*}"//' in.csv > out.csv
```

The result:

```
cat out.csv 
1,2,4,,1
1,2,4,,2
1,2,4,1,3
```